# Returning text of checked radio button

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to return the text of the "checked" radio button. The HTML structure is generated by a template and is rendered like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="Y" checked="checked" >Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="N" >No</input>
<input type="radio" name="whatever"value="NA" >Not Applicable</input>
```

I am able to get the value like so:

```
collection.find("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
  var checked = $(this).find(':checked').val();
});
```

I was expecting to be able to use .text() or .html() instead of .val() but neither seem to work. How can I get the var checked = "Yes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. `input` only has a short tag, so it doesn't expect to have text-node between start and end-tag. You should use a `label` for your text:

```js
$('.collection').find("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
  var checked = $(this).find(':checked').val();
  var text = $(this).parent('label').text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collection">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="whatever" value="Y" checked="checked" />Yes
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="whatever" value="N" />No
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="whatever" value="NA" />Not Applicable
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nextSibling` to return text node that is next to input and `textContent` to return text. Also `input` can't contain text and they don't have closing tags.

```js
var text = $('input:radio:checked')[0].nextSibling.textContent;
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="Y" checked="checked" >Yes
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="N" >No
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="NA" >Not Applicable
```

Comment: I like this answer the most. The others probably demonstrate better practices, in using labels to hold text that refers to the input, but this way utilizes the HTML that OP posted, and OP said the HTML is generated (why it's generated with closing tags, though, I haven't the slightest).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/w6kqak6w/1/

```js
$("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
  var checked = $("input[type='radio']:checked")[0].nextSibling.textContent;
  console.log(checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="Y" checked="checked" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="N" />No
<input type="radio" name="whatever"value="NA" />Not Applicable
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct text property for input field, So use label or span:

```js
$("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
  var checked = $(this).find(':checked').val();
  var text = $(this).next('label').text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="radio" name="whatever" value="Y" checked="checked" /><label>Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="whatever" value="N" /><label>No</label>
  <input type="radio" name="whatever" value="NA" /><label>Not Applicable</label>
```